# Are there any utilities to know where a file is physically present in the hdd?

Tags: debian, filesystems, ext4, ntfs, defragmentation

I am on Debian testing and using ext4 and ntfs . while ext4 has been brilliant in recovering lost data sometimes it also discards some pieces when electricity goes for a long time or any such similar event.

The same is the case for ntfs filesystem as well.

For this and other purposes I have been curious to know if there is a utility or way to know where any file resides on the hdd.

It would also help in asserting or discrediting the claim that ext4 or similar filesystems tend to bunch parts of a file in adjoining 'sectors' and hence don't need a defragmenter as its needed in MS-Windows systems.

I would be also interested in knowing if ntfs filesystems also have something similar. I know they use fuse as a glue to be able to access the filesystem.

Comment: BTW, you should read up on "journalling", how it is implemented in ext4 and NTFS, and exactly what parts "go away" because of a power failure, and how mount options can influence that. That's probably more important than finding tools to access internals. Also, NTFS is a Windows file system, and AFAIK the Linux driver still doesn't handle all of it (there are cases when it can't write, because Windows left it in a state it doesn't understand). I wouldn't recommend to use NTFS as your daily filesystem under Linux.

Comment: See also [How can I find out a file's range of LBA's using its inode?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/106857)

Answer (score 2):

There are probably a couple of options. I was able to use debugfs with the filename and the imap command to get what I think you're looking for.

```
$ sudo debugfs /dev/sda1 #(or your filesystem)
> imap /path/to/your/file
Inode 133409 is part of block group 16 located at block 524466, offset 0x000.
```

Comment: Umm... sorry I just updated the answer, maybe you can also share the other query as well.